# Jquery Validate - Unable to get the validator working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I have a form which I want to validate but I cannot get the validator working.

the main page is in ASP.NET C#.
I have the main  tag and will be using an ajax callout on the submitHandler to submit the form.
Inside the form tag, I have a div which is a jquery dialog box. Inside that div, I have all the fields and the button to submit the form (which is actually a button with a jquery .click event).

Fields are like this:

```
<input class="last_name_class modal__input__font" id="lastname" style="width:100%;" type="text" value="" runat="server" />
```

This is the button to submit

```
<input class="btn_red" id="btn_Submit" type="button" value="CREATE CUSTOMER" />
```

When the button is clicked, it fires this:

```
$('#btn_Submit').click(function () {
    $('#form1').valid();
});
```

And this is my validate() function

```
 $('#form1').validate({

            rules: {
                <%=lastname.ClientID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },
                <%=firstnames.UniqueID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },
                <%=dob.UniqueID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },
                <%=addressline1.UniqueID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },
                <%=suburb.UniqueID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },
                <%=state.UniqueID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },
                <%=postcode.UniqueID%> :{
                    required: true,
                },

            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                alert(element);
                $(element).addClass(errorClass);
                $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").addClass(errorClass);
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
                $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                // do other things for a valid form
                //form.submit();

            }
        });
```

When I click on the button nothing seems to happen. I can't even tell if the validate is being triggered.

Thanks

Comment: Did you put all the required jQuery scripts for it?

Comment: I have the following 4 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery validation works on element name, check this line:

```
<input class="last_name_class modal__input__font" id="lastname" style="width:100%;" type="text" value="" runat="server" />
```

there is no name specified. Change this to:

```
<input class="last_name_class modal__input__font" id="lastname" name="lastname" style="width:100%;" type="text" value="" runat="server" />
```

and try again.

Comment: I tried adding the name field to all my fields but nothing is happening. Is there a way to find out if the validator is being called properly and where it is failing it is called?

Comment: @Saj - not only must you have a `name` on every input, it's *only* the NAME that can be referenced from within the `rules` object.  `<%=lastname.ClientID%>` looks like an `id` to me.

Comment: @Saj, *"Is there a way to find out if the validator is being called properly and where it is failing it is called?"* ~  Since it's client-side (JavaScript), use the JavaScript console in your browser to check for errors, inspect the DOM, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made the changes as per below:rules: {
                    lastname :{
                        required: true,
                    },
                    

                },
but it still does nothing

Comment: @Saj, **again**, use your browser's JavaScript console to check for errors.  Use the browser's DOM inspector to verify the HTML markup & JavaScript are both rendering as expected.

Comment: I have checked the browser console for errors and there are no errors either. I have left but one rule for one field (lastname) and then entered a value in that field and clicked on submit. I have put an alert message in the submithandler to see if that fires but nothing happens there. It's almost as though the validator nevers fires

Comment: One thing I noticed is that this is the way the field is generated when looked at on the browser console <input name="ctl00$ContentMainSection$lastname" type="text" id="ContentMainSection_lastname" class="last_name_class modal__input__font" style="width:100%;">

Comment: @Saj , that's the root problem you need to solve.  The names of the elements do not render as expected.